# ImageMagick no encode delegate

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew

I used to be able to convert text to an image using ImageMagick but now I get this error message:

```
$ echo text | convert -background none text:- file
convert: no encode delegate for this image format `TEXT' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1167.
```

ImageMagick was installed using Homebrew

```
imagemagick: stable 7.0.7-10 (bottled), HEAD
Tools and libraries to manipulate images in many formats
https://www.imagemagick.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.7-10 (1,523 files, 23.1MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-11-10 at 15:46:33
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/imagemagick.rb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IM 7, convert is replaced by magick. You also have not specified an output image format for "file". Try this:

```
echo "text" | magick -background none text:- file.png
```

or

```
echo "text" | magick -background none text:- PNG32:file
```

That works for me on IM 7.0.7.10 Q16 Mac OSX

What do you get from

```
magick -version
```

Does it include freetype?

If not, then you probably need to install Freetype with ImageMagick via Homebrew

Comment: Thanks! The output format was the trick for me.  The format is defaulting to the current format when writing unless you force to be a different format for output.  Sometimes if the output file ends with '.jpg' it will work fine, but explicitly saying what output type ensures no confusion.